# how to run symfony2 command in background as daemon

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I have a command that looks like the following:

```
php bin/console rabbitmq:multiple-consumer -w run_task
```

the command above has an endless while loop, its meant to be that way because its a listener that listens from the queue. Is there a way to put this command to run in the background so that I don't have to have 10 terminal tab always open? If not what is the solution

Comment: You can use something like Supervisor (http://supervisord.org/) to run the command you want in the same way the JMS Job Bundle runner does here - http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/installation#setting-up-supervisord

Comment: @adit How did you solve this one?

Comment: Too bad it's not easy to get supervisord running on shared hosting :/

Answer (score 0):

For me this question is more OS specific than PHP. I would solve this by using system-tools which make it possible to run tasks in background e.g. screen (linux).

If you want a command that does this you are able to write an wrapper command using the symfony process component where you could run the real task in a screen-instance.